# Data processing task for bioinformatics

Tags: c, parsing, bioinformatics

I threw together this C program today to handle a bioinformatics data processing task. The program seems to work correctly, but I wanted to know if anyone has suggestions regarding how the input data are parsed and how I've used control structures in the main processing loop.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 1024

FILE *fileopen(const char *filename, const char *mode)
{
  FILE *fh = fopen(filename, mode);
  if(fh == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "error: unable to open file '%s'\n", filename);
    exit(1);
  }
  return fh;
}

void *memalloc(size_t size)
{
  void *memory = malloc(size);
  if(memory == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "error: unable to allocate memory\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  return memory;
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
  // Parse command line arguments
  char seqbuffer1[BUFFERSIZE];
  char seqbuffer2[BUFFERSIZE];
  char qualbuffer1[BUFFERSIZE];
  char qualbuffer2[BUFFERSIZE];
  char *seqbufferout;
  FILE *seqinfile;
  FILE *seqoutfile;
  FILE *qualinfile;
  FILE *qualoutfile;
  int seqlength;
  if(argc != 6)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "error: 5 arguments required, %d provided\n", argc - 1);
    exit(1);
  }
  seqinfile   = fileopen(argv[1], "r");
  qualinfile  = fileopen(argv[2], "r");
  seqoutfile  = fileopen(argv[3], "w");
  qualoutfile = fileopen(argv[4], "w");
  seqlength   = atoi(argv[5]);
  assert(seqlength > 0);

  // Process reads
  seqbufferout = (char *)memalloc( sizeof(char) * (seqlength + 1) );
  seqbufferout[seqlength] = '\0';
  while(fgets(seqbuffer1, BUFFERSIZE, seqinfile))
  {
    if(strlen(seqbuffer1) > 0)
    {
      int ambiguous;
      int i;

      assert(strncmp(seqbuffer1, ">", 1) == 0);
      if(fgets(seqbuffer2, BUFFERSIZE, seqinfile) == NULL)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: file ends with a fasta header\n");
        exit(1);
      }

      if( fgets(qualbuffer1, BUFFERSIZE, qualinfile) == NULL || 
          fgets(qualbuffer2, BUFFERSIZE, qualinfile) == NULL )
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: no quality entry corresponding to sequence '%s'\n", seqbuffer1);
        exit(1);
      }

      ambiguous = 0;
      for(i = 0; i < seqlength; i++)
      {
        if(seqbuffer2[i] == '.')
        {
          ambiguous = 1;
          break;
        }
        seqbufferout[i] = seqbuffer2[i];
      }

      if(!ambiguous)
      {
        fprintf(seqoutfile,  "%s%s\n", seqbuffer1, seqbufferout);
        fputs(qualbuffer1, qualoutfile);

        i = 0;
        char *tok = strtok(qualbuffer2, " ");
        while(tok != NULL && i < seqlength - 1)
        {
          if(i > 0)
            fputs(" ", qualoutfile);
          fputs(tok, qualoutfile);
          tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
          i++;
        }
        fputs("\n", qualoutfile);
      }
    }
  }

  fclose(seqinfile);
  fclose(qualinfile);
  fclose(seqoutfile);
  fclose(qualoutfile);
  free(seqbufferout);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the big indent block you make by doing `if(strlen(seqbuffer1) > 0)`, do: `if (strlen(seqbuffer1) <1) continue;`, so the entire rest of the loop can be outdented a level, making it more readable.

Similarly, you can turn the `if(!ambiguous)` into `if (ambiguous) continue;` and outdent that block as well.

Depending on what version of C you're using, ambiguous could be a `boolean` instead of an `int`.

You could be a little more consistent with your NULL comparisons to the result of fgets() - the one in the while() condition is implicitly `!= NULL` but the ones in the if() statements are explicitly `== NULL`. IMO you should be either explicit everywhere or implicit everywhere - either choice is fine, but mixing styles makes your code a bit more unclear.

`assert(strncmp(seqbuffer1, ">", 1) == 0);` is the same as the more-easily-understood `assert(seqbuffer1[0] == '>')`, right?

Also, you've got at least one potential bug: What if BUFFERSIZE is smaller than input line length and then seqlength > BUFFERSIZE?

Comment: While I agree that large statements are hard to read, I think continue is even worse, it leads to spaghetti and is generally considered bad practice (it is banned by MISRA-C for example). Instead, use functions. `if(strlen(seqbuffer1) > 0)) parse_string(seqbuffer);` This is how you make programs clearer.

Comment: `continue` can really only exacerbate spaghetti code, not cause it: it's only unclear if it's in the middle of a large block... but I'd argue that's a problem with having a large block, not with `continue`.

Comment: Here is an example of spaghetti caused solely by the continue keyword: `for(i=0; i<condition; i++)
{
  if(something)
  {  continue; }

  a[count] = b[i];
  count++;
}`  The code is hard to read, because it is not obvious to the reader when `i` and `count` are increased respectively.

Comment: Apart from that, the general definition of spaghetti no matter programming language, is usually "code that jumps both upwards and downwards". Code that only jumps downwards is usually considered acceptable, even if it is using goto. C language `continue` does not fit in anywhere, except in code jumping upwards.

Comment: I think that can be argued both ways; http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=238 argues opposite to you.

Answer (score 1):

General comments:

- use `perror` instead of `fprintf` on error
- use EXIT_FAILURE as an exit code on failure

main()

- `seqbufferout` and hence `memalloc()` are redundant
- but as it is, the call to `memalloc` should omit `sizeof(char)`, which is 1 by default and should omit the cast.
- fgets calls maybe use `sizeof buf` instead of BUFFERSIZE
- is `fgets(seqbuffer1...) != NULL` and `strlen(seqbuffer1) == 0` a possible combination?  I don't think so - in which case the strlen is redundant
- assert on `seqbuffer1[0] == '>'`, not on a strcmp
- for-loops like this that do a well-defined task should be extracted into a function
- but this for loops seems just to look for a '.'; `strchr` would be better
- copying `seqbuffer2` to `seqbufferout` seems redundant as you just print the contents of `seqbufferout`
- the while loop should be extracted into a separate function; it looks as if the loop just strips leading and trailing spaces and multiple spaces from the `qualbuffer2` string - is that right?
- so (unless I misunderstood the purpose of the code) the stuff from and including `ambiguous = 0` becomes:

  ```
  if (!strchr(seqbuffer2, '.'))
  {
      fprintf(seqoutfile,  "%s%s\n", seqbuffer1, seqbuffer2);
      fputs(qualbuffer1, qualoutfile);
      fputs(strip_spaces(qualbuffer2), qualoutfile);
      fputs("\n", qualoutfile);
  }
  ```
- no checks for error in writing to the output files
- no check for error in seqinfile on exit from the main loop.  You need to append the following before closing the files

  ```
  if (ferror(seqinfile)) 
  {
       perror(...); 
       ...
  }
  ```